# 'modinfo --field' possible values?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

`modinfo --field` allows filtering for fields like "autor", "description", which is nice.

**Question**: Where can I find a complete list of possible values for `--field`

What I've tried so far:

- `man 8 modinfo` mentions some "common fields", which leaves me with
  "you might know best what you're looking for"
- Grepping through the
  source code I found little to nothing except in `./kmod-9/tools/modinfo.c`, which didn't help me much as I'm illiterate in C (and yes, I grepped through the whole `kmod` package for quite some terms)
- Kernel Module Programming Guides: see point above
- I might have missed something important...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`modinfo` extracts information from the `.modinfo` section of the kernel module.  The info generally gets in that section because a kernel module author added sections like:

```
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Joe's awesome driver");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Joe Blow<joe@blow.com>");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Perhaps that much is clear - but the point is there is no definitive list, because a driver author could add any freeform info they want, like:

```
MODULE_INFO(my_cool_field, "Wow, so cool");
```

There are simply common fields.

And, the other point of the above is that the `modinfo` program doesn't know about what fields there are - it simply searches for them in the `.modinfo` section module.

Followup:  grepping include/linux/module.h in the Linux source, I see the following macros defined:

```
#define MODULE_ALIAS(_alias) MODULE_INFO(alias, _alias)
#define MODULE_LICENSE(_license) MODULE_INFO(license, _license)
#define MODULE_AUTHOR(_author) MODULE_INFO(author, _author)
#define MODULE_DESCRIPTION(_description) MODULE_INFO(description, _description)
#define MODULE_VERSION(_version) MODULE_INFO(version, _version)
#define MODULE_FIRMWARE(_firmware) MODULE_INFO(firmware, _firmware)
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks;  grepping through `include/linux/module.h` definitely is on my "things I've missed" list! But: Where do you find the / any) " `.modinfo` secition of a module", because I can't find it here (Debian based Linux) - source code, maybe?

Comment: `.modifo` is a "section" of a kernel module binary - that is, a section of of a `.ko` file.

Comment: source code then?

Comment: another view: `awk '{print $1}' /proc/modules |xargs modinfo|sort`